# How do I add this variable onto the same line as a specific variable in a .txt file?

Tags: python, text-files

I want to be able to add the `quantity` on to the same line as the matching `crop`in a .txt file. However, at the moment I get the error: `ValueError: '(whichever string is contained within crop)' is not in list'`. I believe this is because I need to split the elements of each line so that `crop` is compared with the first element on each line only.

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")

with open ('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:
 lines = file.readlines
 index = lines.index(crop)
 lines[index] += ' ' + str(quantity)

file.close ()
```

[The .txt file is formatted like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2MPb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not short/effective solution, but it works:

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")
def crop(crop, quantity):
        file =  open('cropdatabase.txt',"r+")
        lines = file.readlines()       
        linenumber = 0
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            if crop == lines[i].split()[0]:
                linenumber = i
                break
        lines[linenumber] = lines[linenumber][:-1]
        lines[linenumber]+= " " + str(quantity)+'\n'
        text = "".join(lines)
        file.close()
        file2  = open('cropdatabase.txt',"w")
        file2.write(text)
        file2.close()

crop(crop, quantity)
```